# Specify elasticsearch index in the payload

Tags: json, elasticsearch, indexing

## My query

I am writing an [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) query and specifying the requested `index` in the URL and the query in an external JSON file:

### `curl`

```
curl -s \
     -u $user:$pass \
     https://example.com:9243/index_name/search 
     -d @query.json
```

### `query.json`

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "source:*.log",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
      "include": ["message", "@timestamp"],
      "exclude": "_*"
  }
}
```

## My problem

I would like to state the index name in the query file, rather than the URL.

## What have I tried

- Adding an `index` or `_index` field to various places in `query.json`
- Adding [`"terms": { "_index": "filebeat*" }` to the `query` object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html)

## My question

What's the right way to specify an index in the

Answer (score 0):

Look at [indices query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-query.html), there you will see that you can set the index inside the json query.

If you have any problem let me know.